# Mupx fail deployment with settings.json

Tags: meteor, deployment, kadira

For those who use `Digital Ocean` for hosting and `mupx` for deployment: 
I can not successfully implement usage of `settings.json` file to run on deployment. Previously it caused failure of deployment, and now, for instance, when I tried to add the package `okgrow:analytics`, it doesn't work and this appear on browser console:

> Missing analyticsSettings in **Meteor.settings.public**

although it is there.

```
{
  "public": {
    "analyticsSettings": {
      "Google Analytics" : {
        "trackingId": "xxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When running locally, one has to type `meteor --settings settings.json` to start the app. Is there something equivalent for the `mupx`? How can I configure accordingly?

Needless to say, I need settings.json for sensitive data which shall be ignored for git as well. Perhaps just `meteor` command should first check if `settings.json` exists, and accordingly run with the settings inside (if any). Then one doesn't need to type `meteor --settings settings.json`...

Comment: How does your `settings.json` file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised my problem was due to having the settings.json file in the root of the project rather than within the mupx deploy folder.

It was sufficient, then, to just run `mupx deploy`